# How to add entries to a database table within a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I just forgot how to do this and cannot find a helpful tutorial on the internet.

It is possible to setup a db table and then to fill it with data within the migration.

So I got my db `"persons"` with `t.column :name => :string` and want to add a person after the dbs creation. It was something like `Person.add :name => "Nobody"`... But I forgot how the method is called exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .. `Person.create(:name => 'nobody')`

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for... such a simple question but when you just forgot the methods name.......

Comment: You might want to use the more forcefull `Person.create!`, though. The version [with the bang](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-create-21) raises an exception when it cannot be saved, e.g. due to validation issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use krunal shah's sample in seed.rb. Then run rake task `rake db:seed`

Comment: it works in self.up... then first the table creation and under this Person.create....

Answer (score 0):

You should never create new data in a migration. You can change existing data though.

To fill the database, you should use `seeds`.

This makes for a clean separation between defining the schema (migrations) and filling it with the correct data. One could assume you will need to change your seeds more often (e.g. a new look-up value is added). Seeding the database is an easy step, should be repeatable, and not effect the rest of the data.

Comment: I disagree. When you e.g. extract enums into actual models, it makes perfectly sense to `create!` some data. Say you have a `User.role` which is `admin` or `visitor` and later on decide to make it a full-fledged `Role` model in a `roles` table: you'll be best off actually creating existing `Roles` in the migration.

Comment: I understand your point of view. As said: I prefer to separate the data from the schema definition. I assume my data can change more often than my schema. Upon deploy I always run both migrations and seeds. Also not sure what happens with data in `schema.rb`, so will `rake db:setup` still work?